# Oracle Apex - ToolTip per Interactive Grid row

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a basic Interactive Grid on my page, edit is on for updates.
This is my table:e

```
create table fruits_t
(
id NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 
9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 ORDER  NOCYCLE  
NOKEEP  NOSCALE  NOT NULL ENABLE, 
fruit_name varchar2(100),
fruit_color varchar2(100)
)

insert into fruits_t (fruit_name, fruit_color)
values ('banana', 'yellow')

insert into fruits_t (fruit_name, fruit_color)
values ('apple', 'red')

insert into fruits_t (fruit_name, fruit_color)
values ('lemon', 'green')
```

How can I add a tooltip per row so that when the user hovers on the Banana row it displays  'Banana is yellow'?

Thanks